# Como activar un checkbox al escribir o cargar información en un textbox?

Tags: php, mysql

Quisiera saber como podría hacer esto, he investigado y no he logrado encontrara nada similar, no se si es posible y de serlo así si no fuera mucho pedir un pequeño ejemplo para entender gracias de ante mano.

Quiero saber esto, para poder hacer una evaluación de un empleado si pertenece a cierta área de trabajo, hacerle ciertos exámenes médicos entonces al escribir el área de trabajo que solo se habiliten los exámenes que son necesarios en su área de trabajo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos para esto debes usar algo de JavaScript o Jquery en este caso lo hare con JavaScript como los machos :)

Codigo:

```js
//obtengo el div examenes
divExamenes = document.getElementById('divExamenes');
//oculto el div examanes
divExamenes.style.display= 'none';

function mostrarExamenes(){
 diagnostico = document.getElementById('diagnostico');
  if(diagnostico != '' || diagnostico != null){
    //mostrar div examenes
   divExamenes.style.display= 'block';
  }
}//end function mostrarExamenes
```

```html
<label for="diagnostico">
Diagnostico:</label><br>
<textarea name="diagnostico" id="diagnostico" rows="4" onkeyup="mostrarExamenes();"></textarea>
<div id="divExamenes">
<label for="">Examen de Sangre
  <input type="checkbox" name="examen1" id="examen1">
</label>
</div>
```

Si te fijas tengo declarado un textArea en el cual puedes escribir lo que deseas "diagnostico", una vez empiezes a escribir mediante el evento **onkeyup** llamo a una funcion "**mostrarExamenes**" la misma que como su nombre lo dice muestra el div que por defecto al cargar la pagina esta oculto.

todo esto lo hace mediante sus respectivos ID.

Te sugiero revisar lo siguiente:

[Evento onkeyup JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp)

[Show/hide mostrar/ocultar JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp)

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación

Answer (score 1):

A mi me gusta esta técnica, porque además lo práctica y clara que es refleja una la lógica adaptada a la situación real de un eventual modelo de datos.

La clave de todo es este objeto:

```
{
    "1": ["Test a", "Test b", "Test c"],
    "2": ["Test d", "Test f"],
    "3": ["Test g", "Test h", "Test i"]
}
```

Supongamos que tienes las áreas `Tecnología, Salud y Enseñanza`, cada con un `id`, y luego tienes una tabla donde relacionas cada test con su área:

#### A.

Una simple consulta de la bases de datos te podría producir un objeto parecido al de más arriba.

#### B.

Supongamos que el `select` se construye de forma dinámica. Asignas al `value`  el `id` de cada elemento

#### C.

En Javascript escuchas los cambios del `select`, buscando dentro el objeto que contiene la información de los test por medio del `id`.

Luego construyes `checkbox` (o lo que quieras) con la información y lo presentas en el `div`.

Por ejemplo (está todo explicado en el código):

```js
/* Estructura que relaciona areas/tests */
var mAreasTests = `{"1":["Test a","Test b","Test c"],"2":["Test d","Test f"],"3":["Test g","Test h", "Test i"]}`;
/* La conviertimos a JSON */
var json = JSON.parse(mAreasTests);
/* Referencia al contenedor */
var divTests = document.getElementById('allTests');

/* Listener para cada vez que cambie una opción */
document.getElementById('workAreas').onchange = function() {
  /* Valor de la opción seleccionada */
  var mId = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  /* Buscamos el array de tests por la clave dada */
  var mTests = json[mId];
  /* Usamos map para construir los checkboxes */
  var arr = mTests.map(function(i) {
    return `<input type="checkbox" id="cbox${i}" />${i}<br />`;
  });
  /* Los mostramos en el contenedor */
  allTests.innerHTML = arr.join('');
};
```

```html
<select id="workAreas">
  <option value="" data-qty="" data-price="" data-city="" selected>--Seleccione área--</option>
  <option value="1">Tecnología</option>
  <option value="2">Salud</option>
  <option value="3">Enseñanza</option>
</select>
<hr />
<div id="allTests">
</div>
```

Esta lógica es perfectamente adaptable a todo tipo de situaciones según la necesidad. Por ejemplo, en lugar de tener los datos en un objeto JSON, se podrían poner en un atributo de datos de cada elemento... cosas sí. Lo importante es que se está codificando en consonancia con lo que tenemos almacenado. Y todo se hace de forma dinámica y transparente.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Genial sigues **sorprendiendome** con tus respuestas, no sabia del _map_ gran explicación..!!